# Arduinoの商用(組み込み)のライセンスについて

Tags: arduino, ライセンス, gpl, mit-license

Arduinoの商用(組み込み)のライセンスについて2つ質問です。
一つは
[Arduinoの公式ページの商用利用の項目](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-xbT-m8_XAhVDm5QKHQygBp0QygQILjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.arduino.cc%2Fen%2FMain%2FFAQ%23toc10&usg=AOvVaw07X73T9n0R8wS6P-055_jZ)(Can I build a commercial product based on Arduino?)
において回答として
*"Using the Arduino core and libraries for the firmware of a commercial product does not require you to release the source code for the firmware. The LGPL does, however, require you to make available object files that allow for the relinking of the firmware against updated versions of the Arduino core and libraries. Any modifications to the core and libraries must be released under the LGPL."*
との記載があります。
これはArduinoのライブラリやコア自体はLGPLであるものの、これらを改変せず用いれば組み込みとしての頒布においては自身で書いたスケッチはLGPLに縛られることはないとの解釈でよろしいのでしょうか。

二つ目は、GPLライブラリをリンクしたスケッチを書き込んだ1台目のArduinoと、サードパーティー製のMIT,Apache2.0,BSDライセンスのライブラリを書き込んだ別の2台目のArduinoをシリアル通信で動作させる組み込みシステムを制作した場合、この2台目のArduinoに書き込んでいるスケッチはGPL感染を避けることができますでしょうか。

ライセンスなどに詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ざっと和訳してみると
[A]
"Using the Arduino core and libraries for the firmware of a commercial product does not require you to release the source code for the firmware.”
商用製品にArduino coreおよびlibrariesをファームウェアとして利用する際には、ファームウェアのソースコードの提示は求められない。

[B]
The LGPL does, however, require you to make available object files that allow for the relinking of the firmware against updated versions of the Arduino core and libraries.
しかしLGPLは、アップデートされたArduino coreおよびlibraryと再リンクできるようにオブジェクトファイルを提供可能とするよう求めている。

[C]
Any modifications to the core and libraries must be released under the LGPL.
Arduino coreおよびlibrariesを改変した場合には、LGPLに基づいて提示しなければならない。

==
質問者が自作のライブラリをスケッチで作って、そのライブラリをArduinoのフラッシュメモリの書き込んだ状態で商品として売り出すには、[B]の部分に基づいてオブジェクトファイルの提供（Web等からダウンロードできるようにする、要求フォーム等で依頼すればメール等で送ってもらえるようにする等）が必要ということです。
この意味で「スケッチはLGPLに縛られる」という事になります。

これはArduinoがバージョンアップされることによって、既に市場に出ているArduinoベースのシステムが動かなくなる事を避けるための方策でしょう。

Comment: Fumu7さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
オブジェクトファイルの点についてはLGPLに縛られるということなんですね。